# Flutter: Google Auth Android Error during sign-in: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-oauth, google-signin

I keep getting this error:

```
Error during sign-in: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

Yes, I have checked many of the other similar questions.

When I run `./gradlew signingReport` I get the Sha-1 and Sha256 and I have attached them to Firebase Settings for android, and have redownloaded the google-services.json file.

Can someone please help with other possibilities?

I did change the name of the application frmo com.example... to com....

Will that make a differnece?